# Swift UINavigationBar background image does not cover status bar when clipToBounds is true

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm setting the background image of a large title navigation bar like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    
    self.title = "Nav bar"
    
    let largeTitleAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    largeTitleAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    largeTitleAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "kunal-shinde--f0YLss50Bs-unsplash")
    largeTitleAppearance.backgroundImageContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    largeTitleAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    largeTitleAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = largeTitleAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = largeTitleAppearance
}
```

However, the image overflows out of the navigation bar as shown here:

[image]

I thought `clipsToBounds` might work so I set it to true at the end of `viewDidLoad`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

[image]

This is better, but the image does not cover the status bar! How can I get it to cover the status bar while not overflowing?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Dennis no, but I just made the navigation bar completely transparent and manually added an image view as a subview. This problem was from 2 years ago though. I'll give it another shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've solved this as followed:

We set the background image on ViewController. This is the same as we use in navigation bar.

```swift
let imageView = UIImageView(image: .assetImage(.background))
imageView.contentMode = .topLeft
collectionView.backgroundView = imageView
```

Style the navigation bar.

```swift
// General Styling
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .assetColor(.navigationBarTintColor)
        
// Bar Styling
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: .assetImage(.background)!)
        
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
```

In addition we change the translucent of the navigation bar for non-root views:

```swift
if isRootview {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
} else {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Comment: Hmm nice, using an image as a color is cool